# Android JSONObject vs. GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am not able to understand the difference between JSONObject and GSON for parsing JSON strings in Android.

Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

GSON can use the Object definition to directly create an object of the desired type. JSONObject needs to be parsed manually. Thats the main difference.

Answer (score 4):

as the others said, `GSON` should make mapping `JSON` to `POJO` much easier, BUT, the latest `GSON` version (as I write, 2.2.2) has serious issues with the latest Android API 17 (Android 4.2).

Check this for information: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=496

If you are doing a new project now, and want it to be compatible with Android 4.2, either use an older `GSON` (1.7.1 works fine with Android 4.2, but is slower), or find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

What Tim is said correct also,

Gson is the best API for JSON parsing on Android. It has a very small 
binary size (under 200 KiB), does fast databinding, and has a simple 
easy-to-use API. Android's built-in JSON libraries are also good. You 
should use them if you aren't doing much JSON and don't need 
databinding.

Answer (score 0):

There are two JSON APIs on Android:

org.json is a simple, tree-style API. It's biggest weakness is that it 
requires you to load the entire JSON document into a string before you 
can parse it. For large JSON documents this may be inefficient. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

android.util.JsonReader/JsonWriter are low-level streaming APIs. 
They're efficient but don't do databinding, so you need to write some 
boilerplate code to use these. They're only available in Android 3+. 
For earlier versions of Android the same API is available standalone 
in Gson's stream package. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Gson's JsonReader and JsonWriter are derived from Android's JsonReader 
and JsonWriter. I literally copied and pasted them from Android into 
Gson one day, and try to keep them in sync as I optimize one or the 
other.

Comment: By far the biggest weakness of the `org.json` implementation is `JSONException`.  It's just _not convenient_ to have to place a `try/catch` block around all of your JSON stuff.

Comment: Thanks @aroth for adding valuable comment.